# How to write a single quote in a different alphabet

Tags: greek, alphabet

I'm looking for a way to include a single quote in ancient greek at the beginning of one chapter of my thesis currently in english. How can I change the alphabet in just a small section of my document?
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `babel` you can load multiple languages. Note that the last language loaded is the default language for the document, thus `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` will load both English and Greek but English will be set as the default language. With the `\begin{otherlanguage}{<language>}` environment you can locally change the language.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
Αυτή είναι μια πρόταση στα ελληνικά
\end{otherlanguage}

And this is a sentence in English.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking the answer as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about). Thanks a lot! I hope you enjoy your stay in our great community.